# How to login directly to the phpBB Administration Control Panel (phpBB 3.0.12) with a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, authentication, phpbb, phpbb3

Are you bored of logging in first to the phpBB3 Front Panel, then do much more Clicks to finally get to the phpBB Administration Control Panel? How can you get directly and auotmated to the phpBB3 Administration Control Panel?

Comment: You should post your script as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code snippet. It is perfect acceptable to answer yourself to your question, but please, follow the StackOverflow format: (1) post the question (2) **provide the solution as a self-accepted answer**. This is really important both for future visitors and for search engines at this will mark the question as solved. In addition, this allows other participant to provide their own solution.

Comment: just as an aside, the whole point of having to authenticate yourself again is an extra layer of security (and is there by design, not to inconvenience people), and by removing this you are leaving your ACP one step closer to attack.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this little bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# phpBB Automated and Direct Login to Administration Control Panel
# Version: phpBB SEO 3.0.12
# This phpBB version does not use cookies at all, it only works with Session-IDs (sid)
# If your phpBB version works with cookies, try to use the the "-c" option in curl to write a cookie-file
# and the "-b" command to load a cookie-file

LOGINURL="http://yoursite.com/phpbb/ucp.php?mode=login"
LOGINURL_ADM="http://yoursite.com/phpbb/adm/index.php"
BOARDURL="http://yoursite.com/phpbb/index.php"
# IMPORTANT: In this script you have to use the same User Agent as your Browser does, otherwise it won't work.
# find it out for example on: http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/
USERAGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0" 

# Login Data
USERNAME="yourAdminAccount"
PASSWORD="yourAdminPassowrdTopSecret"

# Login to phpBB like a normal user
curl -s -d "username=$USERNAME" \
        -d "password=$PASSWORD" \
        -d "login=Login" --user-agent "$USERAGENT" $LOGINURL -o "login.html"

# Get Session ID for this Login
SID=$(egrep  -o "sid.*\>" login.html | sed -n '1p' | sed 's/sid=//')
echo "sid= $SID"

# Now go to the Administration Control Panel Login Area
curl -s --user-agent "$USERAGENT" "$LOGINURL_ADM?sid=$SID" -o "login_adm.html"

# And get the "credential"-value, which is essential
credential=$(egrep  -o "credential.*\>" login_adm.html | sed -n '1p' | sed 's/credential" value="//')
echo "credential=$credential"

# Login to the Administration Control Panel, POST all essential data including the "credential"-value
curl -s -d "credential=$credential" \
        -d "login=Login" \
        -d "username=$USERNAME" \
        -d "password_$credential=$PASSWORD" \
        -d "redirect=./../adm/index.php?sid=$SID" \
        --user-agent "$USERAGENT" "$LOGINURL_ADM?sid=$SID" -o "login_adm2.html"

echo ""
# Let's see, if everything worked:
# Error:
cat login_adm2.html | grep "Access to the Administration Control Panel is not allowed as you do not have administrative permissions." | sed 's/\t<p>//' | sed 's/<\/p>.*//'
# Success:
cat login_adm2.html | grep "You have successfully authenticated and will now be redirected to the Administration Control Panel." | sed 's/\t<p>//' | sed 's/<br \/>.*//'

# Get the new Session ID:
SID_ADM=$(egrep  -o "sid.*\>" login_adm2.html | sed -n '1p' | sed 's/sid=//')
echo "old sid = $SID"
echo "new sid = $SID_ADM"

# Start the browser, whose User Agent you specified at the beginning of this script
firefox "$LOGINURL_ADM?sid=$SID_ADM"
firefox "$BOARDURL?sid=$SID_ADM"

# Clean up
rm login.html
rm login_adm.html
rm login_adm2.html

exit
```